# Specify ggplot2 bar stacking by z variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a Gantt chart for my research project, however I would like to organise the bars so that tasks of the same 'type' are grouped together.

I have attempted to do this through:

```
df$Type <- factor(df$Type, levels = c("Research Proposal", "Planning", "Data Collection", "Data Analysis", "Writing", "Skills and Development", "Annual Leave"))
```

which nicely organised my legend, and had no effect on the bars.

Here is my code at present:

```
ggplot(df) +
    geom_segment(aes(
        x = as.POSIXct(as.Date(Start, "%d/%m/%Y")), 
        xend = as.POSIXct(as.Date(End, "%d/%m/%Y")), 
        y = Task, 
        yend = Task, 
        colour = Type), size=10) +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
labs(title = "GANTT Chart", subtitle = "xxx")`
```

Which creates the following:

[image]

Any ideas appreciated - perhaps I need to reorder within the data frame?

Comment: You need to post your data for that. Also, it's unclear how you want them grouped. Same position on y-axis? Then it won't be possible to differentiate between `Task`.

Comment: You probably need to make `Task` a factor and reorder the levels according to type.